GCP example snippet not in docs for PubSubReactiveFactory. GCP-PubSub
I am trying to understand how to use PubSubReactiveFactory. I currently am using ChannelAdapter route in SpringBoot to consume the stream from Pub/Sub and getting out of memory as there is no backpressure.
Not able to find examples on how to use
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/main/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spring/pubsub/reactive/PubSubReactiveFactory.java
I want to do this in springboot

This is the sample code for PubSubReactiveFactory. It does not, however, explain its usage with ChannelAdapter.
